# GAS button or input[submit] keeps refreshing page? why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, google-apps-script, form-submit

I've just started a new Google app script and created a simple form with some jQuery behind it to handle the validation, shown below.

But whenever I click on the `<button>` I created, it just refreshes the page. The same thing happens with a `<input type='submit'>` button.

Any ideas why this is doing his and how to prevent it?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<!-- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/css -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<!-- this CSS package is for the jquery datepicker  -->

<div>
  <h1>Use the form below to enter a new entry into the calendar</h1>
  
  <table>
  <form>
  
    <tr>
      <td>
          Title: <input type='input' id='title' />
      </td>
      <td>
          Description:<input type='input' id='description' />
      </td>
     </tr>
     
     
    <tr>
      <td>
          Date: <input type='text' id='date_choice' value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
          <label for="select">Time of day</label>
          <select id="select">
            <option value='before' >Before School Starts</option>
            <option value='morning' selected>Morning</option>
            <option value='lunchtime'>Lunchtime / Afternoon</option>
            <option value='afterschool'>After School has ended</option>
          </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
   
   
   
   <tr>
     <td colspan='2' style='text-align: center;'>
        <button class="create">Insert</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#date_choice" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
  });
  
  $("#create").click(InsertIntoCal);
});

function InsertIntoCal(){
  
  var title = document.getElementById("title").value; 
  var descr = document.getElementById("description").value; 
  var date = document.getElementById("date_choice").value; 
  var time = document.getElementById("select").value; 
  
  alert(title); alert(descr); alert(date); alert(time);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made a simple HTML / jQuery mistake. Your button has a `class`, but no unique `id`:

```
<button class="create">Insert</button>
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...yet you attempt to bind a `click()` handler to a specific element by `id`:

```
$("#create").click(InsertIntoCal);
   ^^^^^^^
```

As a result, `InsertIntoCal()` never gets called.

You want that `class` for styling, so keep it but add an `id` like so:

```
<button class="create" id="insert-entry">Insert</button>
```

Then modify the binding to use the new `id`:

```
$("#insert-entry").click(InsertIntoCal);
```

You can try it out in the snippet below.

WRT `<input type='submit'>` - that will not work in Google Apps Script, there's no `POST` handler waiting for form submissions. Instead, you need to keep extending your `InsertIntoCal()` handler to use [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to send the form contents to a server-side handler.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<!-- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/css -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<!-- this CSS package is for the jquery datepicker  -->

<div>
  <h1>Use the form below to enter a new entry into the calendar</h1>
  
  <table>
  <form>
  
    <tr>
      <td>
          Title: <input type='input' id='title' />
      </td>
      <td>
          Description:<input type='input' id='description' />
      </td>
     </tr>
     
     
    <tr>
      <td>
          Date: <input type='text' id='date_choice' value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
          <label for="select">Time of day</label>
          <select id="select">
            <option value='before' >Before School Starts</option>
            <option value='morning' selected>Morning</option>
            <option value='lunchtime'>Lunchtime / Afternoon</option>
            <option value='afterschool'>After School has ended</option>
          </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
   
   
   
   <tr>
     <td colspan='2' style='text-align: center;'>
        <button class="create" id="insert-entry">Insert</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#date_choice" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
  });
  
  $("#insert-entry").click(InsertIntoCal);
});

function InsertIntoCal(){
  
  var title = document.getElementById("title").value; 
  var descr = document.getElementById("description").value; 
  var date = document.getElementById("date_choice").value; 
  var time = document.getElementById("select").value; 
  
  alert(title); alert(descr); alert(date); alert(time);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the refresh, try to get the button outside of the form tags.